# How to format OffsetdateTime to ISO 8601 string with milliseconds precision in java 17?

Tags: jackson-databind

I am running some code in a container with java 17 installed .
I am using jackson databind ObjectMapper to  serialize java objects to the json data. Here is how i have configured Object mapper

```
JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule(); 
    module.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new JsonSerializer<OffsetDateTime>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider arg2)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                 logger.info("OffsetDateTime serialize called");
                 jsonGenerator.writeString(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").format(offsetDateTime));

        }
    });
    

    mapper.registerModule(module);

    mapper.registerModule(new JsonNullableModule());
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    mapper.configOverride(BigDecimal.class).setFormat(JsonFormat.Value.forShape(JsonFormat.Shape.STRING));
}
```

However when i access my endpoint using curl the json output has a timestamp with nano second precision. The following is an attribute in the json response.I want the timestamp in milliseconds precision. How can I achieve that?

```
"time":"2024-01-26T16:36:37.633244661Z"
```

appreciate any help
thank you